# How to check if a key is present in NSArray populated with json data in SWIFT?

Tags: json, swift, nsjsonserialization

i am trying to parse this json response.

```
account =     (
            {
            accountName = "Complete Access";
            accountNumber = "062005 1709 5888";
            available = "226.76";
            balance = "246.76";
        }
    );


var account : NSArray = jsonResult.valueForKey("account") as NSArray
```

Now, this array contains all value for key “account”. Inside this array how we can check if it contains the key “balance” or not.I tried to check it as below :

```
if account .containsObject(account(idx).valueForKey(“balance"))
 {
    transactions.balance = account(idx).valueForKey(“balance”) as? String
 }
```

But, it never got inside the if condition. Please sugget the correct way to achieve this.

Comment: Can you please be more specific than "did not work"?

Comment: It never got inside the if loop

Comment: The JSON response you have given is not valid JSON.

Comment: it is only a part of json response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this may help on you:

```
let keyAccount: String = "account"
let keyBalance: String = "balance"

var jsonResult : Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["account":[["accountName":"Complete Access", "accountNumber":"062005 1709 5888", "available":"226.76", "balance":"246.76"]]]

var account : AnyObject? = jsonResult[keyAccount]
if let accountArray: Array<AnyObject>? = account as? Array {
    if accountArray!.count > 0 {
        if let accountDictionary: Dictionary<String, String>? = accountArray![0] as? Dictionary {
            if let balanceValue: String? = accountDictionary![keyBalance] {
                println("\(balanceValue)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, because I did not spot the array first.